# To what extent do subobjects in abelian categories behave like submodules?

Tags: category-theory, modules, abelian-categories

I am trying to prove a collection of results about subobjects of abelian categories. With a little work, it’s not hard to show that the subobjects form a distributive lattice. **Note: There is a concrete question I would like answered at the end of this post.**

Given an object $M$ and two monomorphisms $a: A \rightarrowtail M$ and $b: B \rightarrowtail M$, we may construct the meet $a \cap b$ as $ \text{ker}(\text{cok}(b) \circ a)$ and the join $a \cup b$ as $\text{ker}(\text{cok}(a \oplus b))$, where $a \oplus b : A \oplus B \rightarrow M$ is the canonical map out of the biproduct. Denote the domains of these maps by $A \cap B$ and $A \cup B$ respectively.

These constructions are easily seen to be generalizations of the intersection and “internal sum” of submodules. I am interested in figuring out how similar/dissimilar these constructions are in general.

For example, it is clear that while infinite families of submodules always have an intersection, this is not true in all abelian categories.

I would like to prove some similarities though. For example, I would like help resolving the following question:

If we have submodules $A,B \subseteq M$ and a linear map $\phi : N \rightarrow M$, we may pullback $A$ and $B$ to submodules $\phi^{-1}(A)$ and $\phi^{-1}(B)$ of $N$. This can easily be accomplished in an arbitrary abelian category by taking pullbacks. However in the module case, it is clear that if $A \cup B \cong M$, then $\phi^{-1}(A) \cup \phi^{-1}(B) \cong N$. Does this extend to all Abelian categories as well?

I have tried multiple approaches, but nothing has panned out. Help and suggestions would be appreciated. This feels like it should be true, and I’m sure there’s some way to set up a commutative diagram and apply the 4 or 5 lemma, but I don’t see it. Thanks!

Comment: What does $A \cup B$ even mean in an Abelian category? Also, assuming classical logic, $A \cup B = M$ iff either $A \subseteq B$ or vice versa.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should have made that more clear. I’m just using “$A \cup B$” to denote the domain of the kernel $\text{ker}(\text{cok}(a \oplus b))$. The second part of your comment doesn’t make sense to me. For example, we can decompose a vector space into sub spaces.

Comment: There is a big huge theorem here that lets you sweep away all such questions in a certain sense, so it sounds like you have heard of it. But it might spoil your fun.

Comment: @KevinArlin would you mind telling me the name of the theorem? I’ve been skimming through lots of material on abelian categories, but I might not have come across some useful tools. I don’t want to spoil my fun either, but I’d like knowing where to look when I *stop* having fun

Comment: @Joe Sure, it's the Freyd-Mitchell embedding theorem.

Comment: @Joe I meant $\cup$ in the ordinary sense of union. The union of two subspaces is itself a subspace if and only if one is a subset of the other (though this can only be proved by contradiction).

Comment: @MarkSaving Oh ok I see what you mean. I was using $\cup$ to denote the join of subobjects. Thank you for clarifying :)